# Discrepancy in Recent warning to Fix mobile usability issues

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, googlebot-mobile

Our website has a desktop version and a separate mobile version (/mobile) which is determined in the .htaccess file when mobile users access the site they are taken specifically to the mobile site. Recently, we were notified inside Google Webmaster Tools to "Fix mobile usability issues" and it listed the following errors:

1. Viewport not configured
2. Small font size
3. Touch elements too close
4. Content not sized to viewport

However, when we go to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/
The website checks out and reports "Awesome! This page is mobile-friendly"

I then noticed inside of the Google Webmaster tools there is only ONE sitemap for the desktop version. Do we need to add a new sitemap.xml inside /mobile directory? I'm guessing that maybe Google isn't aware of the /mobile directory and only considered the desktop sitemap, is that possible?

Thanks in advance

**.htaccess file**

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobile/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|operamobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you see this regarding sitemaps? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34648?hl=en There is also this one regarding how to alert bots to mobile url schema in general: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/configurations/separate-urls?hl=en

Comment: Are you just using the htaccess to redirect mobile users?

Comment: Yes, the htaccess is taking care of it and simply adds /mobile to URL. The mobile site is only 1 index.html page. I added a sitemap onto webmaster tools for the /mobile but seems that the google bot hasn't picked it up yet.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .htaccess file and the mobile webpage source code?

Comment: @Mike I've added the .htaccess file above in the post. Also you can go here to see the mobile webpage http://bit.ly/1HPyw7z 
I did recently add a separate sitemap inside the /mobile dir but google bot hasn't indexed it yet.

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Even after updating sitemaps the issue still persists :(